# Session key not timing out when set in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, session

Here's some relevant detail from my config file:

```
    'rememberUsernameDuration' => false,
    'rememberedUserSessionDuration' => false,
    'userSessionDuration' => 'PT30S'
```

I'm expecting to see sessions timing out after 30 seconds but they don't seem to be, and if I remove that they are still valid beyond the default time.

Now, one thing I'm doing is setting a session directly in a plugin:

```
craft()->httpSession->add('myKey', 'myData');
```

And retrieving:

```
craft()->httpSession->get('myKey');
```

Am I missing something here? The config file definitely affects the Craft CMS login session as with the config above I get constant warnings to keep my session open in the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing Craft's [userSessionDuration](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#userSessionDuration) - which is the amount of time that you can stay logged into the control panel - with PHP's [session](https://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) (which is what [craft()->httpSession](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpSessionService) is a wrapper for).

When you get logged out of the control panel, the former userSession is killed, but you still keep the same underlying PHP session ID and cookie.